# What's the difference between intval and db_escape in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-injection

I've got friends who's telling me to change some code.

One of them is telling me to change my code into:

```
intval($_GET['id']);
```

And the other tells me to change into:

```
db_escape($_GET);
```

Who is right, and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intval is specifically for numbers. With intval you transform anything what is not a valid number to "0". With db_escape() you can prepare strings and other stuff to be inserted into a database.
So both are right, it depends on what you want to insert :-) If you want to insert a number or if you want to select an entry with its id

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = " . intval($GET_["id"]);
```

then you should use intval. If you want to insert a text, you should use db_escape.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table (stringCol) VALUES('" . db_escape($_POST['string']) . "')";
```